# Can Endermen and spiders deal damage through doors as zombies do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can endermen and spiders hit the player through the door as zombies do this with both villagers and players?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any mob can, but i believe the movement AI of spiders and endermen would need very specific circumstances and would make it very unlikely.